# CSS3 Animation floating through HTML elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm having some trouble figuring out why the bouncing arrow on my web page is not going behind the rest of the elements on the web page.

I've animated an arrow using CSS3 with the following code

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
-o-animation-fill-mode:both;  
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-fill-mode:both;
-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-moz-animation-duration:2s;
-ms-animation-duration:2s;
-o-animation-duration:2s;
animation-duration:2s;
```

However, if you scroll on down the page, the arrow can still be seen, especially on the Timeline section and "Where do cats sleep" section. I've tried z-index on a few elements and nothing seems to be fixing it.

You can view it [here](http://www.itssjp.co.uk/infographic)

It's probably something small but can't figure it out, thanks!

Comment: What's the point of having this arrow if you want it to be behind everything?

Comment: @ExplosionPills  I want it visible on the header section only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem kind of silly, but for the `header` use:

```
position: relative;
z-index: -2;
```

Then, for the `.arrow`, use:

```
z-index: -1;
```

It will be behind all `z-index: auto` elements which is pretty much the rest of the page.  The header has to be `position: relative` so the negative z-indices work together.